# Spring Boot 2.5 - unable to convert form data to custom POJO

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I am having difficulty converting an incoming form data to a POJO.
I have a Spring Boot application which receives a POST request from a 3rd party server with content as x-www-form-urlencoded.
The form data is like this:

```
{
    "type": "xyz",
    "data[email]": "test@test.com",
    "data[merges][FN]": "test"
}
```

In my RestController, I have the relevant PostMapping with a custom object created to receive the form data.
However, I am only able to create the custom object and receive simple String parameter like the "type".

ex: This works

```
class MyResponse {

    private String type;
} //WORKS
```

However, if I try to create a Map<String, String> or Map<String, AnotherObj> to parse the remaining fields 'data[email]' & 'data[merges][FN]', it does not work.

If I simply use Map<String, String> request instead of a custom object, the data is empty.
If I use '@RequestBody Map<String, String> request', it throws 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE

If I add another inner class Data property like this to my custom object:

```
private Map<String, Data> data;
```

it throws an error:

```
Invalid property 'data[merges][FN]' of bean class [...MyResponse]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'data[merges][FN]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [...MyResponse$Data@26f008e0]
```

I even looked at this example for guidance, but could not find a solution:
https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/convert/NestedBean.java

What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 0):

Properties with square brackets are still strings, not a collection.
You can try to deserialize these non-standard field names from the JSON using Jackson.
Reference: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson.
You POJO would look like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyResponse {

    private final String type;
    private final String dataEmail;
    private final String dataMergesFn;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyResponse(
            @JsonProperty("type") String type,
            @JsonProperty("data[email]") String dataEmail,
            @JsonProperty("data[merges][FN]") String dataMergesFn) {
        this.type = type;
        this.dataEmail = dataEmail;
        this.dataMergesFn = dataMergesFn;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getDataEmail() {
        return dataEmail;
    }

    public String getDataMergesFn() {
        return dataMergesFn;
    }
}
```

Your controller will parse that json with `@RequestBody MyResponse myResponse`

Comment: Thanks Yuri. With your POJO, If I use "@RequestBody MyResponse myResponse" in the PostMapping, it throws 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE. However, if I dont mention the keyword '@RequestBody', the form data gets parsed but only 'type' is populated. Both 'data' fields are null.

Comment: Sample curl which I use and the format of form data being sent: 'curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/myhook -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "type=xyz&data[email]=test@test.com&data[merges][FN]=test"'

Comment: Please see this for the standard format of x-www-urlencoded data format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST
Also, check the actual data that comes with your request, the square brackets could be encoded before your data gets to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Finally using ServerWebExchange worked for me:

```
@PostMapping(
  path = "/hook",
  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public Mono<Void> registerWebhook(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {

    return serverWebExchange.getFormData()
        .flatMap(formData -> {
          String type = formData.getFirst("type");
          String email = formData.getFirst("data[email]");
          String mergesFN = formData.getFirst("data[merges][FN]");
          return Mono.empty();
    });
```